# ContainerRequestContext abortWith() does not abort

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

This is my authentication filter:

```
@Secured
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class SecuredFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {

        String authorizationHeader = requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        if (authorizationHeader == null || !authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
             requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
        }

        String token = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer".length()).trim();
        // [...]
        }
}
```

**Why does it not abort and send back the response when the header is missing ?**
Right now I get an obvious NPE at authorizationHeader.substring ...

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html#abortWith-javax.ws.rs.core.Response-) says:

> void abortWith(Response response)
>
> Abort the filter chain with a
>   response. This method breaks the filter chain processing and returns
>   the provided response back to the client. The provided response goes
>   through the chain of applicable response filters. Parameters: response
>   - response to be sent back to the client.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was missing the "return" keyword:

```
if (authorizationHeader == null || !authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
     requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
     return;
}
```

I found the solution [here](http://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jersey-rest-security/) - I guess the sentence in the docs was misleading:

> This method breaks the filter chain processing and returns the
>   provided response back to the client

I thought the "return" was included.

Comment: The method you are overriding is void. So how does returning change the behavior?

Comment: Yes but it returns right away when I want it to, instead of reaching the end of the method.